# capturar erro de duplicidade no mysql com java

Tags: java, mysql, try-catch

Eu estou tentando mostrar uma mensagem que já existe um id cadastrado, mas ele cai no catch que mostra:

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'idusuario'
```

eu quero mostrar que já existe uma id cadastrada.

```
 try {
        conexao=ConexaoBanco.conector();
        pst=conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,nomeusuario);
        pst.setString(2,senha);  
        try{            
            pst.setInt(3,Integer.parseInt(idusuario));
        }catch(SQLException x){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ID JÁ CADASTRADA");
        }
        pst.setString(4,perfil);     
        pst.setString(5,nome);          
        pst.executeUpdate();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        return false;   
    }
```

( O meu nomeusuario é o login, para não ocorrer confusão).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está usando o try/catch no lugar errado. A exceção é lançada na seguinte linha:

```
   pst.executeUpdate();
```

Pode usar o catch que existe mais abaixo para capturar a exceção mais específica que deseja:

```
} catch (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ID JÁ CADASTRADA");
} catch (SQLException e) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
     return false;   
}
```

Comment: Então, eu não posso ter idusuario nem nomeusuario iguais. Como eu separaria os dois erros para mostrar o  erro "certo" para o usuário?

Comment: Vide minha edição.

Comment: na hora que postou eu postei também :p, vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Espero que funcione, porque não consigo melhorar a resposta. Entrei no SOpt por reflexo, estou ligeiramente "alto". Com a informação de onde a exceção é disparada você já deve ser capaz de fazer algo a respeito. Boa sorte.

Comment: então eu coloquei isso e realmente funciona ele captura, mas até pro nomeusuario ele está jogando na tela "id já cadastrada"

Comment: esperava uma ajuda pra essa última questão, mas obrigado de qualquer forma.

Comment: Só se tentar fazer alguma gambiarra. A mais inócua que consigo pensar é usar o `getMessage()` da exceção para pegar o nome do campo já cadastrado e montar uma mensagem para o usuário com base nele. Ou então guardar em uma variável o nome do campo sendo atribuído e se basear nessa variável para mostrar a mensagem ao usuário dentro do tratamento da exceção.